# Finding all ids available at a particular time

Tags: r, data.table

I have a binary matrix that gives the indication whether a person (ID) is available at a time to do a job.  The example matrix is

```
08:00 08:30 09:00 09:30 10:00 10:30 11:00 11:30 12:00 12:30 13:00 13:30 14:00 14:30 15:00 15:30 16:00 16:30 17:00 17:30 18:00 18:30 19:00
1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
2     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
3     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
4     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
5     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
6     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
  19:30
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
```

The row names represent the IDs and the time showed are the ones where the IDs are available.  In the example, IDs 1 and 2 start work at 8:00,  and have specific break periods at 10:30-11:00, 13:00- 13:30.  The persons that start half and hour later 3 and 4 takes break from 11:00-11:30, 13:30-14:00.  This is to ensure that somebody is available to do a job that can start at any particular point.

dput(matrix)

```
structure(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), .Dim = c(6L, 24L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"), c("08:00", "08:30", "09:00", "09:30", "10:00", "10:30", 
"11:00", "11:30", "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", 
"14:30", "15:00", "15:30", "16:00", "16:30", "17:00", "17:30", 
"18:00", "18:30", "19:00", "19:30")))
```

Another dataset have the "IDs" with their starting time

```
data1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:6, Start_Time = c("8:00", "8:00", "8:30", 
             "8:30", "9:00", "9:30"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

A third dataset will have the start and end timings for a particular task

```
 data2 <- data.frame(Start = c("8:01", "9:35", "10:42", "11:25", "14:22", 
    "17:20", "18:19"), End = c("8:22", "9:42", "11:20", "11:32", 
    "14:35", "18:15", "18:25"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I am trying to create a column in data2 that gives the IDs available to do the task based on the Start time in data2.  The expected output is

```
data2$IdsAvail <- c("1, 2", "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6", "3, 4, 5, 6", 
  "1, 2, 5, 6", "1, 2, 3, 4", "3, 4, 5, 6", NA)
```

It would look like below

data2

```
 Start   End         IdsAvail
1  8:01  8:22             1, 2
2  9:35  9:42 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
3 10:42 11:20       3, 4, 5, 6
4 11:25 11:32       1, 2, 5, 6
5 14:22 14:35       1, 2, 3, 4
6 17:20 18:15       3, 4, 5, 6
7 18:19 18:25             <NA>
```

Tried to match the IDs with time in the matrix, but couldn't find a way.  It is also possible that two jobs can come within the time frame where one person is doing a job.  I am not taking that into consideration here.  This just to get the initial IDs available based on the matrix.

EDIT: The below solution by @Audiophile works for the example, but it throws a warning here having duplicates

```
availability <- merge(availability,data2,by.x = 'time',by.y = 'slot',all.y = T)
```

I had to use `allow.cartesian` to make it work in the original dataset.  My dataset have about 2000 rows, after using merge it gives about >20000 rows. The above `merge` step using this example also give different number of rows than in 'availability' or 'data2'.  Is there any other method i.e. using `foverlaps` from `data.table`?

Answer (score 2):

Identify the slots for which each person is available, and then merge it with the task list:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#Convert your availability matrix (mat1) to a data frame
df <- as.data.frame(mat1)
df$ID <- rownames(df)

#Reshape the availability dataset
availability <- df %>%
  gather(time,available,-ID) %>%
  filter(available==1) %>%
  mutate(time = as.POSIXct(time,format = "%H:%M"))

data1$Start_Time <- as.POSIXct(data1$Start_Time,format = "%H:%M")
data2$Start <- as.POSIXct(data2$Start,format = "%H:%M")

#Use start times to refine availability dataset
availability <- merge(availability,data1,by = "ID")
availability <- availability %>%
  filter(time>=Start_Time) %>%
  select(ID,time)

#Round task time to nearest half hour slot
data2$slot <- as.POSIXct(floor(as.double(data2$Start)/1800)*1800,
                         format = "%H:%M",origin = as.POSIXct('1970-01-01',tz='UTC'))


availability <- merge(availability,data2,by.x = 'time',by.y = 'slot',all.y = T)

availability <- availability %>%
  select(Start,End,ID) %>%
  arrange(Start,ID) %>%
  group_by(Start,End) %>%
  summarise(IdsAvail = toString(ID)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Start = format(Start,"%H:%M"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It works fine with the example but shows some error about duplicates while running `merge(availability,data2,by.x = 'time',by.y = 'slot',all.y = T)` in the original dataset.  So, I have to use `allow.cartesian=TRUE`  Is there any compact way?